# How can I set a policy to enable public key authentication only if the pubkey has a password that meets requirements?

Tags: authentication, key-authentication

How can I set a policy to enable public key authentication only if the pubkey has a password that meets requirements?

Currently people make keys with `ssh-keygen`. We want to enforce creation and use of keys with passwords that meet standards.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you want to replace `ssh-keygen` with your own version that does passphrase checking. You can probably do this with a wrapper script. You'll also need to deny access to any version of a key generator that does not meet your standards.

Comment: This is not directly possible. A password protected key is just an encrypted key so from the key itself you can see if it is protected, but on the server side you can't even tell that because you will only have the public unencrypted key. What you could do is set up your own service for generating keys and then request a password from the user, check it, generate the key pair and allow them to download the private, then only allow access from keys that were generated by your service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enforcing decent protection of the user's private key cannot be enforced. Even if you would implement a custom replacement for ssh-keygen you cannot prevent the user from extracting the private key and store it in clear-text on a network share.

You simply have to trust the user to follow your security guide-lines. You may want to implement custom tools to guide the user doing the right thing.

Two options:

1. You could implement a secure process for provisioning hardware key
   tokens and lock down the token device. So the user would not have to
   deal with the private key file. Caveat is that you have to install client-side software to support the key tokens.
2. Another option is setting up a SSH-CA which issues short-term OpenSSH user certificates (not X.509 certs) which are only valid for a few hours. Still the user could manipulate the SSH-CA client and extract the private key. But it would only be abusable for the short cert lifetime. This mainly only works for OpenSSH client and servers and libssh-based stuff.